# Rename file extension using case and recursion

Tags: bash

Can someone create a short code that will rename a files extension in a sub directory using a command line option -r?

So if i have a file a.txt in folder called loc. I enter this "change -r txt doc" and the file will become a.doc in the loc sub directory (as in loc/a.doc).

I need to add this to a code of mine. Also the reason why I want to use a case statement is because I will be adding more options in the future.

Comment: Have you tried?  What didn't work?  Please ask a specific question.

Comment: I just can't do it. I looked at an example of a case statement and I don't know how to apply it to this. I'm trying to add it to this:

for newext in *$.txt 
do 
  export NAME=`basename $newext $.txt` 
  mv $NAME$.txt $NAME$2.doc
done

Comment: Seems weird to want to rename .txt into .doc. And to write a custom script with options to do a `find ... -exec mv "{}" ...` Anyway, it may be worth noting that some distributions have a nice rename command taking Perl regexes: `rename 's/\.txt$/.doc/' *.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to change file extensions recursively.

Script `change.sh`:

```
# recursive rename:       ./change.sh -r -f txt -t doc
# current directory only: ./change.sh -f txt -t doc

find_depth="-maxdepth 1"    # defaults to current directory

while getopts "rf:t:" Option
do
case $Option in
    f ) from=$OPTARG ;;
    t ) to=$OPTARG ;;
    r ) find_depth="" ;;
esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1)) 

for file in $(find . $find_depth -name "*.$from")
do 
    mv $file "${file/.$from/.$to}"
done
```

Edited in response to your comment.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Some questions, how do I apply that to a case (i want to use a case for this task, since i want to add more options)? And what if I want to specify any file extension, do I use $1 and $2? How will that work?

Comment: -1. what if file names have spaces? and since using bash, use `$()` instead of backticks

Comment: I removed the spaces around the `=` in your variable assignments.

Comment: Thanks lecodesportif! I think I can work with something like that. About the case....I want to have 3 options: 1. if the user enters "change -r txt doc", a file extension gets changed in a subdirectory. 2. If the user enters nothing, "change txt doc", it just changes a file extension in the current directory. 3. But if a user enters "newext -n -r doc", it should rename files that end with .-r or .-n (this will rename all files in the current directory called *.-r as *.doc)

Comment: My edit answers your points 1 and 2. Your point 3 is unclear, but it should be easy to change the example.

Answer (score 1):

To get extension and use `case/esac`

```
extension=${filename##*.}
case "$extension" in
  "doc" ) ... ;;
  "txt" ) ... ;;
esac
```